# Filtering Objects entries in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, powershell-5.0

I started today to play with PowerShell and wanted to do a simple task. Read all my installed software, filter out "Microsoft related entries + null entries" and store them in JSON file.

Well, I was able to do that but I couldn't figure out the filtering part mostly because the whole script language is new to me and I couldn't successfully iterate to remove the entries I wanted.

Your help is appreciated!

```
$outputFile="C:\test.JSON"
$GetAppData= Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* |Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate

    foreach ($Applications in $GetAppData.PSObject) 
    {

        foreach ($App in $Applications.Properties.Value) 
        {
         if ($App.'DisplayName' -like '*Microsoft*' -or !$App.'DisplayName' ) 
                {
                    $Applications.Value.PSObject.Properties.Remove($App)  
                }
         }
    }    
     
    $GetAppData| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $outputFile -Force
```

Comment: are you trying to use, `!$App.'DisplayName'`, as a means of it being null/empty?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simpler way to get the info is to use the somewhat newer `Get-Package` cmdlet. [*grin*]

what the code does ...

- sets the item pattern to exclude
  you could make this into a regex `OR` list to exclude more than one item.
- gets the list of all packages
- filters out the MSU items
- filters out the items with a blank `.Name` property
- filters out the items that match the `$DoNotWant` pattern
- saves the list to the `$Result` collection
- displays the list on screen

you could add other steps to sort by name, rearrange the properties, or otherwise customize the props in the final objects.

the code ...

```
$DoNotWant = 'microsoft'

$Result = Get-Package |
    Where-Object {
        $_.ProviderName -ne 'msu' -and
        $_.Name -and
        $_.Name -notmatch $DoNotWant
        }

$Result
```

truncated output ...

```
Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------
7-Zip 19.00 (x64)              19.00                                             Programs
AutoHotkey 1.1.33.02           1.1.33.02                                         Programs
Bulk Rename Utility 3.3.2.1...                                                   Programs

[*...snip...*] 

PSFileTransfer                 5.31.0           https://www.powershellgallery... PowerShellGet
PSFramework                    1.4.150          https://www.powershellgallery... PowerShellGet
PSLog                          5.31.0           https://www.powershellgallery... PowerShellGet
PackageManagement              1.4.7            https://www.powershellgallery... PowerShellGet
```

Comment: This Works! Thank you very much. silly question: How was $Result linked to the $GetAppData without being mentioned in the code.

Comment: Answering my own question: Get-Package. :D

Comment: @ShortCircuit - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit. ///// yep ... almost any PoSh code block can be assigned to a $Var. it's the recommended way to save things to an array since it avoids the nasty gotcha when using `+=` on an array ... arrays are _fixed size_. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

For your specific question, this is how you can filter and export your `$GetAppData`. There are several ways of filtering an array and also there are some cmdlets / functions that can give you the same result as querying HKLM.

```
$outputFile="C:\test.JSON"
$GetAppData= Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* |Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate

$GetAppData.Where({$_.DisplayName -and $_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Microsoft'})|ConvertTo-Json > $outputFile
```

Cheers!

Comment: Also an acceptable solution. Thank you for the assistance.